# using httpx to send 100K get requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, get, python-asyncio, httpx

I'm using the `httpx` library and `asyncio` to try and send about 100K of get requests.

I ran the code and received `httpx.ConnectError` so I opened `wireshark` and saw that I was getting a lot of messages saying `TCP Retransmission TCP Port numbers reused` [image: wireshark image]

when I saw the data in `wireshark` and the error `httpx.ConnectError` I added `limits = httpx.Limits(max_connections=10000)` to limit the amount of active connections to 10,000 **but I still get that error.**

my code:

```
import asyncio
import json
import httpx


SOME_URL = "some url"
ANOTHER_URL = "another url"
MAX = 10000


async def search():
    guids = [guid for guid in range(688001, 800000)]  # 688001 - 838611
    timeout = httpx.Timeout(None)
    limits = httpx.Limits(max_connections=MAX)

    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=timeout, limits=limits) as client:
        tasks = [client.get(f"{SOME_URL}{guid}", timeout=timeout) for guid in guids]

        blob_list = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  # <---- error from here !!!!!

        blob_list = [(res, guid) for res, guid in zip(blob_list, guids)]

    guids = [guid for res, guid in blob_list]
    blob_list = [json.loads(res.text)["blob_name"] for res, guid in blob_list]

    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=timeout, limits=limits) as client:
        tasks = [client.get(f"{ANOTHER_URL}{blob}", timeout=timeout) for blob in blob_list]

        game_results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)  # <---- error from here !!!!!

        game_results = [(res, guid) for res, guid in zip(game_results, guids)]

    game_results = [guid for res, guid in game_results]

    print(game_results)


def main():
    asyncio.run(search())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

this is a minimal version of my code there some steps in between the requests that I deleted, but I didn't touch the code that made the trouble, there are comments on the lines that I receive the errors (# <---- error from here !!!!!).

does anyone know how to solve this? or another way to send about 100K of get requests fast?

Comment: are you sure the server can handle the load?

Comment: yes the server can handle the load @nullsteph

Comment: Do you know of another way to send a large amount of get requests fast?

Comment: Is that on Windows ? I am seeing this error also on Windows, but not Linux.

Comment: yes it is on windows @Damien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem with the following code:

(this is not the entire code, only the parts needed to send the requests, I have some stuff in between)

```
import asyncio

from aiohttp import ClientSession


SOME_URL = "some url"
ANOTHER_URL = "another url"
MAX_SIM_CONNS = 50
worker_responses = []


async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.read()


async def fetch_worker(url_queue: asyncio.Queue):
    global worker_responses
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            url = await url_queue.get()
            try:
                if url is None:
                    return
                response = await fetch(url, session)
                worker_responses.append(response)
            finally:
                url_queue.task_done()
                # calling task_done() is necessary for the url_queue.join() to work correctly


async def fetch_all(base_url: str, range_: range):
    url_queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=10000)
    worker_tasks = []
    for i in range(MAX_SIM_CONNS):
        wt = asyncio.create_task(fetch_worker(url_queue))
        worker_tasks.append(wt)
    for i in range_:
        await url_queue.put(f"{base_url}{i}")
    for i in range(MAX_SIM_CONNS):
        # tell the workers that the work is done
        await url_queue.put(None)
    await url_queue.join()
    await asyncio.gather(*worker_tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    asyncio.run(fetch_all(SOME_URL, range(680_842, 840_423)))
    print(worker_responses)
```

I used `aiohttp` instead of `httpx` and used `asyncio.Queue` to reduce RAM usage and it worked for me.